# "Pas classe" or "pas de classe"?

Tags: articles, négation, de

In a French textbook, it was printed "Il n'y a pas classe." Is there no need for 'de' in this negative sentence?

Should it not be "Il n'y a pas de classe"?

Answer (score 5):

The verb “*avoir*” can take a direct complement which is a noun without an article to indicate that some scheduled activity takes place. This can work both with “*il y a*” (“there is”) and with a subject (who the person who performs this activity). Only a few complements are in common use, though this is a productive construction: you can use any activity if the context is clear.

“*Il n'y a pas classe*” means that a specific class or the whole school does not take place. This can be due to special events or a regular thing.

> Il n'y a pas classe à 14h, le professeur est malade.   (*There's no class at 2pm, the teacher is off sick.*)
> Il n'y a pas classe aujourd'hui à cause de la neige.   (*There's no class today due to snow.*)
> Il n'y a pas classe aujourd'hui puisque c'est dimanche.   (*There's no class today because it's Sunday.*)

With all of these sentences, you can say “*Je n'ai pas classe*” if you're a student (or the teacher). In the positive form, there is no preposition or article before the noun.

> J'ai classe à 14h, le professeur est remplacé.
> La neige a fondu, il y a classe aujourd'hui.
> Réveille-toi ! Les vacances sont finies ! Tu as classe aujourd'hui !

“*Il n'y a pas de classe*” would have a different meaning. It can have several different meanings, in fact, depending on context: it just means that the class/classroom/lesson does not exist. As a whole sentence, it would be a little weird in a school context. The positive form is “*il y a un(e) classe*”: this is the usual case where the indefinite article is *de* in a negative sentence.

> Il n'y a pas de [salle de] classe dans ce bâtiment, seulement les bureaux de l'administration.   (*There is no classroom in this building, only the admin office.*)
> Il n'y a jamais de classe après 17h.   (*Classes never extend pass 5pm.*)
> Il y a une classe qui commence à 8h.   (*There's a class that starts at 8am.*)
> J'ai une classe de sixième cette année, mais je n'ai pas de classe de cinquième.   (*I have [= I'm teaching] a first form this year, but I don't have any second form.*)

Some other examples of “*avoir*” + noun-without-article:

> J'ai cours de 8h30 à 16h30 aujourd'hui, et j'ai piscine jusqu'à 18h.   (*I have school from 8:30 to 4:30 today, then I'm going swimming until 6.*)
>
> Je peux pas, j'ai piscine.   (Literally “I can't, I'm going to the swimming pool”. Effectively a transparent excuse to decline an invitation, not very polite because it's obviously false.)
>
> Je rentrerai tard ce soir, j'ai comité directeur.   (*I'll be back home late tonight, I have a management committee meeting*. Uncommon, but idiomatic. The long form would be “j'ai une réunion du comité directeur”.)